# How to iterate over a tuple of tuples without flattening

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, tuples

I'd like to check the values of a tuple of tuples. In addition to checking each value of each tuple, I need to also compare the last element in one tuple to the first element in the next tuple.

Can I iterate over a tuple of tuples without flattening it into a list?

```
flattened_tuple = [element for tupl in tupleOfTuples for element in tupl]

for i in range(len(flattened_tuple)-1):
    print(flattened_tuple[i], flattened_tuple[i+1])
```

This is what I came up with that doesn't flatten into a list, but I can't compare last element of one tuple to first element of next tuple:

```
   for row in tuple_of_tuples:
    for i, element in enumerate(tuple_of_tuples):
        print(row[i], row[i+1])
```

For the tuple of tuples: ((0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)), I get this error:

```
0 1
1 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "npuzzle.py", line 67, in goal_test
    print(row[i], row[i+1])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: A nested `for` loop? We need some more information to go off here.

Comment: Show us some code, what have you tried?

Comment: Booo make an attempt

Comment: do not name variables `list`, `max`, `min`, `dict` and so on - you are hiding the built-ins and get into problems

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate over pairs to allow comparison through consecutive tuples, [itertool's recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) suggests the following implementation.

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for last, nxt in pairwise(tupleOfTuples):
    if last[-1] == nxt[0]:
        ...
```

The `pairwise` implementation has the advantage of working with any kind of iterable, including consumables such as generators.

Comment: what would the nestsed for loop look like? My nested for loop wouldn't allow me to compare elements across sub tuples

Comment: @Matt I missed that requirement, have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with taking the last element of the first tuple and then iterate through the rest of the tuples. Based on your question, here is a possible solution:

```
last_element = tuple_of_tuples[0][-1]
for row in tuple_of_tuples[1:]:
    first_element = row[0]
    # compare first element to last element
    # ...
    last_element = row[-1]
```